# Unable to Use Monitor Wrapper with Atari Environments in Stable Baselines 3

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym, stable-baselines, atari-2600

I've been using `stable_baselines3` for recently and successfully applied the `Monitor` wrapper for the classic control problems, like so:

```py
from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
env = Monitor(env, "path_to_log_dir")
```

It saves logs to the log directory, and I can use it to plot the graph to see performance.

However, I ran into issues when I tried applying the same method to Atari environments, specifically while using vectorized environments. Here's a snippet of what I tried:

```py
from stable_baselines3.common.envs import make_atari_env
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack

env = make_atari_env("ALE/BeamRider-v5", n_envs=4)
env = Monitor(env, "path_to_log_dir")
env = VecFrameStack(env, n_stack=4)
```

Upon trying the above, I received an following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 5
      3 env = make_atari_env("ALE/BeamRider-v5", n_envs=4)
      4 # Stack 4 consecutive frames together to provide temporal information
----> 5 env = Monitor(env, logs_dir)
      6 env = VecFrameStack(env, n_stack=4)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/monitor.py:44, in Monitor.__init__(self, env, filename, allow_early_resets, reset_keywords, info_keywords, override_existing)
     42 self.results_writer = None
     43 if filename is not None:
---> 44     env_id = env.spec.id if env.spec is not None else None
     45     self.results_writer = ResultsWriter(
     46         filename,
     47         header={"t_start": self.t_start, "env_id": str(env_id)},
     48         extra_keys=reset_keywords + info_keywords,
     49         override_existing=override_existing,
     50     )
     52 self.reset_keywords = reset_keywords

AttributeError: 'DummyVecEnv' object has no attribute 'spec'
```

I understand that Atari environments are more complex due to being vectorized, and this might be causing the problem.

Could anyone guide me on properly using the `Monitor` wrapper with vectorized Atari environments in `stable_baselines3`? I'd appreciate a solution that explains the steps in simple terms.

Thank you in advance!

I have also raised this question on official GitHub of Stable baseline: https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/1721